# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode' and AttributeError: 'InferenceServerClient' object has no attribute '_stream'

Tags: python, machine-learning, mlops, torchscript, tritonserver

I had two 2 docker container in the server. One is Triton Client Server whose GRPC port I set is 1747. Triton Client Server port had a TorchScript model running on it. The other container is where I want to call `grpcclient.InferenceServerClient` to the Triton container but I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/miniconda/bin/uvicorn", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/user/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1130, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/user/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/user/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 404, in main
    run(
  File "/home/user/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 569, in run
    server.run()
  File "/home/user/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 60, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "/home/user/miniconda/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/home/user/miniconda/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/user/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 67, in serve
    config.load()
  File "/home/user/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 477, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
  File "/home/user/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 21, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "/home/user/miniconda/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "./api_control.py", line 5, in <module>
    import helpers 
  File "./helpers.py", line 79, in <module>
    timi_triton = TritonInferTTS(url=TRITON_URL,model_name=TIMI_MODEL_NAME,model_version=TIMI_MODEL_VERSION)
  File "./triton_client.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.triton_client = grpcclient.InferenceServerClient(url=self.url, verbose=VERBOSE)
  File "/home/user/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tritonclient/grpc/__init__.py", line 273, in __init__
    self._channel = grpc.insecure_channel(url, options=channel_opt)
  File "/home/user/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/__init__.py", line 1977, in insecure_channel
    return _channel.Channel(target, () if options is None else options, None,
  File "/home/user/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 1479, in __init__
    _common.encode(target), _augment_options(core_options, compression),
  File "/home/user/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_common.py", line 74, in encode
    return s.encode('utf8')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
Exception ignored in: <function InferenceServerClient.__del__ at 0x7f41eb398550>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tritonclient/grpc/__init__.py", line 286, in __del__
  File "/home/user/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tritonclient/grpc/__init__.py", line 293, in close
  File "/home/user/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tritonclient/grpc/__init__.py", line 1649, in stop_stream
AttributeError: 'InferenceServerClient' object has no attribute '_stream'
```

Here is the code:

```
import os
import numpy as np

import sys

from functools import partial
import tritonclient.grpc as grpcclient
from tritonclient.utils import *
VERBOSE = False
TRITON_URL = 'localhost:1747'
TIMI_MODEL_NAME = os.getenv("TIMI_MODEL_NAME")
TIMI_MODEL_VERSION = os.getenv('TIMI_MODEL_VERSION')

class TritonInferTTS():
    def __init__(self, url, model_name, model_version):
        self.url = url
        self.model_name = model_name
        self.model_version = model_version

        self.input_name = ['INPUT__0', 'INPUT__1','INPUT__2','INPUT__3','INPUT__4']
        self.output_name = ['OUTPUT__0']
        self.triton_client = grpcclient.InferenceServerClient(url=self.url, verbose=VERBOSE)
        model_metadata = self.triton_client.get_model_metadata(model_name=self.model_name, model_version=self.model_version)
        model_config = self.triton_client.get_model_config(model_name=self.model_name, model_version=self.model_version)

    
    def triton_infer_grpc(self, x, x_length,noise_scale,length_scale,noise_scale_w):
        # x = np.array([x])

        # alpha = np.array([alpha], dtype=np.float32)

        input0 = InferInput(self.input_name[0], x.shape, 'INT64')
        input0 = x

        input1 = InferInput(self.input_name[1], x_length.shape, 'INT64')
        input1 = x_length
        input2 = InferInput(self.input_name[2], noise_scale.shape, 'FP32')
        input2 = noise_scale
        input3 = InferInput(self.input_name[3], length_scale.shape, 'FP32')
        input3 = length_scale
        input4 = InferInput(self.input_name[4], noise_scale_w.shape, 'FP32')
        input4 = noise_scale_w

        output0 = grpcclient.ssInferRequestedOutput(self.output_name[0])
        # output1 = InferRequestedOutput(self.output_name[1])
        
        response = self.triton_client.infer(self.model_name, model_version=self.model_version, inputs=[input0, input1,input2,input3,input4], outputs=[output0])
        audio = response[0]

        return audio
```

Please help me. I'm so desperate

I changed the Triton Url to 'host.docker.internal:1747' and '<my_public_ip>:1747' but i got the same error

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75765328/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-span-when-using-pytube