# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span' when using pytube

Tags: python, attributeerror, pytube

I am having an issue when downloading a video from `pytube` module.
I tried updating `pytube`, downloading it again, and still does not work.
I am using Python 3.11 and this is my code:

```py
def progress_function(stream, chunk, bytes_remaining):
    print("Downloading")
def completed_function(stream, file_path):
    print("download completed")
    messagebox.showinfo(title="Download has completed", message="The video has successfully downloaded")
    
    
def download():
    user_input = str(link.get())
    yt = YouTube(user_input, on_progress_callback=progress_function, on_complete_callback=completed_function)
    print(yt.title)
    print(yt.thumbnail_url)
    video = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
    video.download()
```

And this is the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\---\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948,in __call__
     return self.func(*args)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\---\PycharmProjects\youtube downloader\main.py", line 30, in download
     video = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
             ^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\---\PycharmProjects\youtube downloader\venv\day\QuizGame\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 296, in streams
     return StreamQuery(self.fmt_streams)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\---\PycharmProjects\youtube downloader\venv\day\QuizGame\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 181, in fmt_streams
     extract.apply_signature(stream_manifest, self.vid_info, self.js)
File "C:\Users\---\PycharmProjects\youtube downloader\venv\day\QuizGame\Lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 409, in apply_signature
     cipher = Cipher(js=js)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\---\PycharmProjects\youtube downloader\venv\day\QuizGame\Lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 29, in __init__
     self.throttling_plan = get_throttling_plan(js)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\---\PycharmProjects\youtube downloader\venv\day\QuizGame\Lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 404, in get_throttling_plan
     transform_plan_raw = find_object_from_startpoint(raw_code, match.span()[1] - 1)
                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span'
```

Download a YouTube video using pytube.

Comment: am getting the user input using link = Entry(width=50, font=FONT_, fg="gray") from tkinker

Comment: I tried multiple ones and they all gave me errors, this link was one of them as well https://www.youtube.com/shorts/MXQifLr2THI

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pytube: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span' cipher.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75765213/pytube-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-span-cipher-py)

Answer (score 4):

That's an error in the `pytube` library. It is caused because of some changes YouTube has made on its Java Script code. To fix it take a look at [this](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1498#issuecomment-1472963944) proposal in the `pytube` Github.

Go to your `pytube` library folder, to the file `cipher.py`. Change the line 411 where it says:

```
transform_plan_raw = find_object_from_startpoint(raw_code, match.span()[1] - 1)
```

That regex is the one that raises the error. Instead write:

```
transform_plan_raw = js
```

Eventually `pytube` will release an update and fix this error.