# I failed to use pytube.Youtube.streams. It was still working few days ago

Tags: python, pytube

Recently, I've created a youtube video downloading tool for my bookmark. It is finished and still able to download youtube video. But today when I try to use it, it shows error when I try to run YouTube.streams.

Here's an example code:

```
from pytube import YouTube

yt = YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEQ8CXFWLZU&t=525s")

yd = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Adrian\Desktop\hey.py", line 5, in <module>
    yd = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
  File "C:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 296, in streams
    return StreamQuery(self.fmt_streams)
  File "C:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 181, in fmt_streams
    extract.apply_signature(stream_manifest, self.vid_info, self.js)
  File "C:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 409, in apply_signature
    cipher = Cipher(js=js)
  File "C:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.throttling_plan = get_throttling_plan(js)
  File "C:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 411, in get_throttling_plan
    transform_plan_raw = find_object_from_startpoint(raw_code, match.span()[1] - 1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span'
```

I've also made a exe file of the python code and it also stop working. Looking forward to get an answer.

Comment: I'd imagine YouTube has changed something on their end which has broken `pytube`. See https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1498 where other people are having the same issue.

Comment: thanks, hope the problem can be solved soon.

Comment: There are some solutions in that issue too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span' when using pytube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75765328/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-span-when-using-pytube)

Answer (score 1):

YouTube has most probably changed their code again.

## Quick Solution

In Cipher.py, go to line 411:

```py
transform_plan_raw = find_object_from_startpoint(raw_code, match.span()[1] - 1)
```

Change it to:

```py
transform_plan_raw = js
```

## Explanation

In Cipher.py, at line 407,

```py
transform_start = r"try{" 
plan_regex = re.compile(transform_start) 
match = plan_regex.search(raw_code)
```

In the above code snippet, the `match` object is defined as the regex matches of `plan_regex` (which is `r"try{"`) found in the `raw_code` object. However, when I tried to get what the `raw_code` object actually returns, I got this value:

```js
mma=function(a){var b=a.split(""),c=[1298660008,function(d,e,f,h,l,m){return e(h,l,m)},968655468,function(){for(var d=64,e=[];++d-e.length-32;)switch(d){case 46:d=95;default:e.push(String.fromCharCode(d));case 94:case 95:case 96:break;case 123:d-=76;case 92:case 93:continue;case 58:d=44;case 91:}return e},56115230,-578061081,-516346513,b,-1739695292,-1031455761,/[,\]],[\]];}.
```

As you can notice, there is not a single mention of `try{` here, hence when the `plan_regex.search` method is called for `raw_code`, it finds no matches and return `None`. Therefore, while seeking for the `span` attribute of `match` object, it raises the Error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span'`.

So basically, instead of searching for the `try{` string in the `raw_code`, we're just passing the input `js` parameter to the `transform_plan_raw` object.

Comment: I got the solution from comments but thanks for your explanation, really helps a lot.

Comment: please accept the answer if it helps so that in the future people can easily find the answer